# Flutter: How to keep user logged-in even when app is closed using Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, session, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I'm using Firebase Auth in my Flutter App. User is authenticated and logged in using 'Auth' but when app is closed/cleared from mobile memory, the user is automatically signed out.

How can I keep the user signed-in and have their state/session active even when the App is closed.

Explored similar questions but no satisfied answer was found.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirebaseAuth has this stream called **[authStateChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html)**, which checks the user is present or not. And we can use this stream in Streambuilder:

```
return MaterialApp(
    home: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return HomePage();
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(body: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
        }
        return SignInPage();
      },
    ),
  );
```